# Am i infringing on this existing patent? i have build something based on existing patent ( improved)

Tags: patent-infringement, design-patent, utility-patent

Am I infringing the patent in this case?

https://patents.google.com/patent/USD747895S1/en?oq=award+medal+rack

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUKEx.jpg**strong text**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we cannot do (non)-infringement opinions with any legal value. We can answer how to check for yourself, but you are the one bearing the risk and the question should reflect that you know that.

Answer (score 1):

The cited patent is a design patent. It covers the ornamental design of a functional object. Your question isn't very clear in that I'm not sure what is being communicated by the second link. Is that your product? In any case, with design patents, the question is whether your product looks like what is described in the patent's drawings. I'm not a lawyer and even if I was one, you really shouldn't rely on the internet for legal opinions. I would suggest getting a freedom to operate opinion from a patent attorney.

In addition, it is important to note that this is only a single design patent. There is the potential for other relevant patents to exist. A good start would be to review the patents cited in the linked patent. If you see something close there then look at that document's citations, etc.

Comment: @FirasAbbasi Thank you. After waiting for other answers, it would be great if you would consider accepting the one you find most useful.